# How to not display "-" delete button when in editing mode of UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to enable deleting ONLY on swipe gesture in editing mode of `UITableView`.

How to delete round "-" button from cells and still have that gesture recognized?
is that possible?

i can disable that icon when cell editing style is set to UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone but it's disable also Swipe-To-Delete gesture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` from the `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. This will suppress the buttons but the row will still be editable.

---

You may also want to change the values of `editingAccessoryType` and / or `editingAccessoryView` in your cell subclass to get the exact functionality you're after.

Comment: but that solution disables swipe-to-delete gesture too :(